# Как правильно писать "с востока Европы"?

Tags: грамматика

Правильно писать: "Мы с Востока Европы" или "Мы с востока Европы"?

Answer (score 2):

Стилистически корректно: *мы из Восточной Европы*.

А "*восток Европы*" - с маленькой.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно писать "восток" со строчной буквы, а "Европа" с прописной(заглавной), так как в данном случае восток не является именем собственным, выделяющим объект из ряда однотипных, а лишь указывает направление - часть света, откуда, собственно, мы. А Европа является. Зато, к примеру, В словосочетаниях Южная Америка и Северная Америка всё пишется с заглавных букв, в виду того, что из однотипных объектов - материков они выделяют конкретно свой. Правильно писать   -  " с востока Европы".

Comment: Из Вашего ответа: _восток... лишь указывает направление - **часть** света, откуда, собственно, мы._ Думаю, что правильно **сторона света** — одно из четырёх основных направлений (север, юг, запад, восток).

Comment: На мой взгляд, это синонимы. Объясню: роза ветров делится на четыре основные части и четыре промежуточные. Одна из них - восток . Так же и земной шар, и Европу можно разделить на части. Следовательно, восток может быть как стороной, так и частью. Но соглашусь с вами, Римма, в моем ответе уместнее восток назвать именно стороной, ибо "часть" здесь более подходит к Европе.